# Rails/Rspec/Factory girl: records not associating?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

Here are my factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :account do
    company 'Example, Inc.'
  end

  factory :site do
    association :account
  end

  factory :page do
    association :site
  end
end
```

And a simple request spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Pages" do

  before do
    @account = Factory(:account)
    @site = Factory(:site)
  end

  it "lets me create a new page" do
    visit account_site_pages_path(@account, @site)
    page.should have_content('New Page')
  end

end
```

But I get this failure:

```
Failure/Error: visit account_site_pages_path(@account, @site)
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
 Couldn't find Site with ID=51 [WHERE (`sites`.account_id = 127)]
# <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
# ./spec/requests/pages_spec.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Meaning the site factory is not associated with the proper account, right?  I'm guessing I'm missing something pretty obvious :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `@account` and `@site` aren't connected, which is likely the problem. So do:

```
before do
  @account = Factory(:account)
  @site = Factory(:site, :account => @account)
end
```

That way, your site isn't creating a new account and is instead related to the original account.